# ffmpeg command not working with white space of directory path in Android

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, whitespace, string-formatting

I am working with `FFMPEG` library in which I want to rotate video using this library which works fine if I am `file path` has no any `white space`. But in my case I have white space of video directory (you can see full path in `String commandStr` `onPreExecute()` method of `asynctask`) path then it is not working at all. I have also seen same question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149606/ffmpeg-command-fails-for-file-path-with-white-spaces) and some more but not get any idea how to resolved it properly. Below is my code of MainActivity.class

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    String workFolder = null;
    String demoVideoFolder = null;
    String vkLogPath = null;
    private boolean commandValidationFailedFlag = false;

    private Button btnRun;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GeneralUtils.checkForPermissionsMAndAbove(MainActivity.this, true);


        setIds();
        setListner();


        demoVideoFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/videokit/";

        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, getString(R.string.app_name) + " version: " + GeneralUtils.getVersionName(getApplicationContext()) );
        workFolder = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/";
        vkLogPath = workFolder + "vk.log";

        GeneralUtils.copyLicenseFromAssetsToSDIfNeeded(this, workFolder);
        GeneralUtils.copyDemoVideoFromAssetsToSDIfNeeded(this, demoVideoFolder);


        int rc = GeneralUtils.isLicenseValid(getApplicationContext(), workFolder);
        Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "License check RC: " + rc);
    }

    private void setListner() {
        btnRun.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void setIds() {
        try {
            btnRun =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRun);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.btnRun:

                Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "run clicked.");
                if (GeneralUtils.checkIfFileExistAndNotEmpty(workFolder)) {
                    new TranscdingBackground(MainActivity.this).execute();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), workFolder + " not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public class TranscdingBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>
    {

        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        Activity _act;
        String commandStr;

        public TranscdingBackground (Activity act) {
            _act = act;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

//            commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/in.mp4 -vf rotate=270*(PI/180) /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4";
            commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/in.mp4 -vf rotate=270*(PI/180) /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4";


            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(_act);
            progressDialog.setMessage("FFmpeg4Android Transcoding in progress...");
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        protected Integer doInBackground(String... paths) {
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "doInBackground started...");

            // delete previous log
            boolean isDeleted = GeneralUtils.deleteFileUtil(workFolder + "/vk.log");
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "vk deleted: " + isDeleted);

            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)_act.getSystemService(Activity.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "VK_LOCK");
            Log.d(Prefs.TAG, "Acquire wake lock");
            wakeLock.acquire();



            LoadJNI vk = new LoadJNI();
            try {

                vk.run(GeneralUtils.utilConvertToComplex(commandStr), workFolder, getApplicationContext());

                // copying vk.log (internal native log) to the videokit folder
                GeneralUtils.copyFileToFolder(vkLogPath, demoVideoFolder);

            } catch (CommandValidationException e) {
                Log.e(Prefs.TAG, "vk run exeption.", e);
                commandValidationFailedFlag = true;

            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.e(Prefs.TAG, "vk run exeption.", e);
            }
            finally {
                if (wakeLock.isHeld())
                    wakeLock.release();
                else{
                    Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "Wake lock is already released, doing nothing");
                }
            }
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "doInBackground finished");
            return Integer.valueOf(0);
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "onCancelled");
            //progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onCancelled();
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            Log.i(Prefs.TAG, "onPostExecute");
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // finished Toast
            String rc = null;
            if (commandValidationFailedFlag) {
                rc = "Command Vaidation Failed";
            }
            else {
                rc = GeneralUtils.getReturnCodeFromLog(vkLogPath);
            }
            final String status = rc;
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (status.equals("Transcoding Status: Failed")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Check: " + vkLogPath + " for more information.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Here `onPreExecute()` method I have given video file path.

Answer (score 0):

I thing since you make a command line call, you need on of these:

- **escape some special characters** (like you would need on the command line too)
- **quote the filename** (than you need to escape quotes in the filename)

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response but can you please know me with sample code that how can I integrated exactly. As I have passed the command in  `commandStr` in `TranscdingBackground` class.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your command from String to ArrayList as like below:

```
commandStr = "ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/in.mp4 -vf rotate=270*(PI/180) /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4";

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add("ffmpeg");
            arrayList.add("-y");
            arrayList.add("-i");
            arrayList.add("/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/in.mp4");
            arrayList.add("-vf");
            arrayList.add("rotate=270*(PI/180)");
            arrayList.add("/sdcard/videokit/out.mp4");
```

and change your vk.run(); method as like below :

```
vk.run(GeneralUtils.utilConvertToComplex(commandStr), workFolder, getApplicationContext());

 vk.run(arrayList.toArray(new String[arrayList.size()]), workFolder, getApplicationContext());
```