# How to extract file name from %%b

Tags: batch-file

```
set PATTERNDIR=..\patterns\
set CMODEL= .\fcb.exe
FOR /R %PATTERNDIR% %%b IN (*.iq) DO (

  if exist %%b (
    %CMODEL% -i %%~dpnb.iq -o c_ref.out -p %%~dpnb.par 
    fc /b %%~dpnb.out c_ref.out >> cmp_c_ref.txt
  )  
)
```

Here %%b contains C:\Users\karthiks\Documents\2G\fcb\working\patterns\FCB_SPUR_original\TC_202\FCB
_RA130_CO_900.iq   I want to extract FCB_RA130_CO_900.iq

Can you please help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch Extract path and filename from a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567809/batch-extract-path-and-filename-from-a-variable)

Comment: You should do a little search on internet first. The first entry for "bat extract name from path" on DuckDuck returned as first link another answer on Stack that address this doubt. :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567809/batch-extract-path-and-filename-from-a-variable

Comment: For your information: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
echo %%~nxb
```

should show you the name and extension of the filename in `%%b`. You don't say what you want to do with that name (and you already know the extension, and the fact that it exists).

see

```
for /?
```

from the prompt for documentation.