# Batch variable for folder right next to current

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want `D:\Desktop\Test0\Test1\batch1.bat` to execute `D:\Desktop\Test0\Test2\app.exe` without determing a specific path because the `D:\Desktop\Test0` folder gets moved around a lot.

What is the variable for this? Unfortunately I can't find it because I don't know what the proper name for this intention is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A batch file can refer to itself when using `%0`. According to [this page](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), you can change the returned string by adding `~`-modifiers, like `~f` to get the full path, `~nx` to get the pure file name or `~dp` to get the path to the parent directory, just to list a few.

In you situation, you simply need to use `%~dp0` in the batch file `batch1.bat` to get its container directory, then get one level up `..` to exclude the immediate parent directory `Test1`, and then append the remaining relative path to the program `app.exe`, like this:

```cmd
"%~dp0..\Test2\app.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft.com - Using batch parameters](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true)

If you use these batch file processors you should be able to pull out the parts of the path that you care about and create a new path to app.exe. Don't forget to put quotes around the variables otherwise you will not handle spaces and other special chars in filenames.

Here's an example of similar question: [Batch Extract path and filename from a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567809/batch-extract-path-and-filename-from-a-variable)