# Batch file to go one step back

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm writting a batch file and I want to move some files from root path to **cd ..** root.

I use %~dp0 to find the root path.

Whats the best method to go back one step from root path?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are almost there, just use `%~dp0..`

or if you want it fully resolved, use this trick

```
@echo off
call :resolve "%~dp0.."
goto :eof

:resolve
echo %~f1
goto :eof
```

for an explanation, see this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15568171/30447

Answer (score 1):

`%~dp0` points to the parent directory of the current batch file (including a trailing `\`), `%~dp0..` therefore points to the grand-parent directory of the batch file.

You can use a [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and the [`~f` modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of its variable reference (`%%I`) to resolve the path:

```cmd
for %%I in ("%~dp0..") do echo/%%~fI
```

Comment: Apart from the typo, your answer leaves me with more questions. Does `%~dp0.` point to the parent directory and `%~dp0...` point to the great grand-parent etc. If `%~dp0` expands to the drive letter and path, why do I need to use the `~f ` modifier. Is `"%~dp0.."` not expanded during the parentheses evaluation, therefore passing the fully expanded drive and path to a string as variable `"%%I"`. Why does it need another expansion with `~f`?

Comment: @Compo, why should `%~dp0..` automatically become resolved? `%~dp0` simply expands to drive (`d`) and path (`p`) to the parent directory of the current batch file with trailing `\ `, no matter whether you prepend or append anything like `..`. A `.` points to the same directory (so `anydir\middir\subdir` is the same as `anydir\middir\subdir\.`), `..` points to the parent directory (so `anydir\middir\subdir\..` is the same as `anydir`); there is no `...` (you need to do `anydir\middir\subdir\..\..` to point to `anydir`)...

Comment: @Compo, and what do you mean by "parentheses evaluation"? you mean, that `for` resolves the part after `in` automatically? no, it does not; it does never resolve paths like `anydir\middir\subdir\..\.\..\file.ext`, it only resolves wild-cards (`*`, `?`) when such appear in the last path element (so behind the last `\ `); you need to use the `~f` modifier for the path to become resolved; note that `for` does not access the file system to check whether the path truly exists, unless wild-cards are included...