# How to create an empty text file with specified path using Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

It has to create full folder path, along with the empty file. My requirement is i will get textfile path as argument and if that file doesn't exists, need to create the file.
I thought to get the path first and check if that folder exists, if not create the folder path, Then create empty file using TYPE nul.

Can i get some thing like in java, String subStr = str.subString(0, str.lastIndexOf('.')) , how to do that using windows batch script .Any suggestions plz, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To split path/folder and file names you can use the [answer provided to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252980/how-to-split-the-filename-from-a-full-path-in-batch).

To create an empty file just copy "nothing" into it:

```
copy nul myEmptyFile.txt
```

As an alternative, you could probably redirect empty output, but I guess this is definitely more resource heavy than the previous idea:

```
cmd /c > myEmptyFile.txt
```

Comment: You may want 
    ```copy /Y nul myEmptyFile.txt```
In case the file already exists and you want to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function like this:

```
@Echo OFF

Call :CheckTextFile "C:\Test1\Test.txt"
Call :CheckTextFile "C:\Test2\Test.txt"
Call :CheckTextFile "C:\Test3\Test.txt"
Pause&Exit

:CheckTextFile
(If not exist "%~1" (MKDIR "%~p1" 2>NUL && FSutil File CreateNew "%~p1\%~nx1" 0 1>NUL)) & (GOTO:EOF)
```

Comment: Its not working  with the above code. I am new to writing script files. I tried, below is the output, and program is not exiting.If not exist "C:\Users\pooja\Desktop\ForTesting\tmp.txt"
 (MKDIR "\Users\pooja\Desktop\ForTesting\"   2>NUL  && FSutil File CreateNew "\Users\pooja\Desktop\ForTesting\\tmp.txt" 0  1>NUL ) ) 
 & (GOTO:EOF) and if i saw the print, it's not showing the drive as C.

Comment: and more over can one plz suggest nice site to learn batch scripting

Comment: The function works, don't try to do it manually. in the code that you have pasted you don't starts with a "(", use it to agrupate or will not run, also you are using two "\\" in the FSUTIL path so can't create file,this is the corrected code from your pasted code:          (If not exist "%HomeDrive%\Users\pooja\Desktop\ForTesting\tmp.txt" (MKDIR "%HomeDrive%\Users\pooja\Desktop\ForTesting" 2>NUL && FSutil File CreateNew "%HomeDrive%\Users\pooja\Desktop\ForTesting\tmp.txt" 0 1>NUL )) & (GOTO:EOF)         if my answer resolved your problem then please use the accept button to accept the answer

Comment: @echo on
Call :CheckTextFile "C:\Users\pooja\Desktop\ForTesting\tmp.txt"
Pause&Exit
:CheckTextFile
(If not exist "%~1" (
MKDIR "%~dp1" 2>NUL && FSutil File CreateNew "%~dp1%~nx1" 0 1>NUL)) & (GOTO:EOF) )
exit . I modified %~p1 to %~dp1, then it giving drive path also. But still its not creating the file. I tried only till MKDIR %~dp1 then its creating the folder. But with the code above its not creating. May be u can correct me, where i am going wrong.