# Remove characters from certain place in string

Tags: batch-file

I have this var (source) which looks like this:

```
\\xxxxx\xxxx\xxx\Companies\test\in\Th FIle Test - Copy - Copy.mp4
```

I would like to remove everything before "\" character. So it would look like this:

```
Th FIle Test - Copy - Copy.mp4
```

I looked at the trim function but not joy. I am using Batch, so I have a bat file.

Comment: Would that work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252980/how-to-split-the-filename-from-a-full-path-in-batch

Comment: @ConnorsFan SPOT ON!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just use regular expressions. I'm unsure of the exact syntax for whatever program you're using, but the regex to search and replace should be relatively easy.

```
Replace .*\\ with '' (nothing)
```

https://regex101.com/r/hQ4hB9/1 <-- you can play around with this. Good website for testing regular expressions.

Comment: Thank for the quick response. Need to get it done in an hour or so. Will let you know.

Comment: Great link but it does not support batch file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the leaf of the path is by using enhanced `for` variable references.

```js
set "var=\\xxxxx\xxxx\xxx\Companies\test\in\Th FIle Test - Copy - Copy.mp4"
for %%I in ("%var%") do set "filename=%%~nxI"
echo %filename%
```

See the last couple of pages of `help for` in a console window for more information.