# batch : Substring in loop with 2 variables

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a loop that loops over files, gets the actual file name (not including the whole path) and tries to check if that file name exists in some list.
the code I have is:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
for /R %%j in (*.c) do (
set MYVAR=%%j
set actualFileName=%%~nj
if NOT "%MY_FILE_LIST%"=="!MY_FILE_LIST:%actualFileName%=!" set "TOCOMPILE=!TOCOMPILE! %MYVAR%"
```

this code does not work since the actualFileName is accessed with % instead of !.
but !MYVAR:~!actualFileName!! doesn't work either.
what can i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split the filename from a full path in batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252980/how-to-split-the-filename-from-a-full-path-in-batch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the `for` replaceable parameter modifiers to get the needed information

```dos
for /r %%j in (*.c) do (
    echo actualFileName is %%~nj
)
```

Where `%%~nj` is the name, without extension, of the file being referenced in `%%j`. See `for /?` for the full list

**edit** to adapt to comments

```dos
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%j in (*.c) do (
    if not "!MY_FILE_LIST:%%~nj!"=="%MY_FILE_LIST%" (
        set "TOCOMPILE=!TOCOMPILE! "%%~fj""
    )
)
```

This should do the job IF no file contains a exclamation in its name. If this can not be ensured

```dos
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%j in (*.c) do (
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if not "!MY_FILE_LIST:%%~nj!"=="%MY_FILE_LIST%" (
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ("!TOCOMPILE! ") do (
            endlocal
            set "TOCOMPILE=%%a"%%~fj""
        )
    ) else endlocal
)
```

Comment: thanks for that!, but my issue now is at the next step.
i've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
for /R %%j in (*.c) do (
 set MYVAR=%%j
 set lastIndex= some calculation to find last index of /


 for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("!lastIndex!") do (
    set actualFileName=!MYVAR:~%%#!
 )

)
```

use another nested FOR