# Get foldername without path using dir in cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, path, command, directory

By using:

```
dir /s /b /o:n /a:d > foldername.txt
```

I get the following output:

```
D:\Project\Java\MyName
D:\Project\Java\Object
```

But I want the output to look like this:

```
MyName
Object
```

The output have to be folder names without their paths?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split the filename from a full path in batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252980/how-to-split-the-filename-from-a-full-path-in-batch)

Comment: Your desired output cannot be achieved by solely using `dir`.

Comment: what to do for getting the desired result?

Comment: Did you take a look at the link in my first comment?

Comment: i looked the link and it is splitting the filename from a full path in batch but mine is directly getting the file name. i got the right answer here. the problem is my question is now having a duplicate flag. how can i remove it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FOR` loop has variable modifiers such that only the file name and extension can be presented. Note that a directory can have an extension. Use `FOR /?` for information about the variable settings.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %d IN (`DIR /S /B /A:D /O:N`) DO (ECHO "%~nxd")
```

Or, to put the names into a file without quoting:

```
DEL foldername.txt
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %d IN (`DIR /S /B /A:D /O:N`) DO (ECHO>>foldername.txt %~nxd)
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
DIR D:\Project\Java\ /b
```

the result will be just like what you want

Comment: That will correctly list the directories within `D:\Project\Java`, but the OP is looking for sub-directories as well (i.e. the `/s` switch).

Comment: This will list the paths too, which is what OP wants to avoid.