# How to get just the name of a folder without path from full folder path in 8.3 format?

Tags: batch-file

How to get just the name of a folder without path from full folder path in 8.3 format?

How can I get the just the name of the target folder under Windows command line?

I have folder strings like these:

```
C:\Users\Fred\DOCUME~1
C:\Users\Fred\Music
C:\Users\Fred\DOWNLO~1\FREEDO~1
```

How can I get just the target folder name using a batch script to get:

```
FREEDO~1
Music
DOCUME~1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split the filename from a full path in batch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252980/how-to-split-the-filename-from-a-full-path-in-batch)

Comment: `for /R C:\Users\Fred /D %%D in (*) do echo %%~snxD` returns all folders in `C:\Users\Fred` in short-name (8.3) format recursively; this will also return `DOWNLO~1` with your example folder structure...

Answer (score 1):

```
dir /ad /b C:\Users\Fred
```

or

```
cd C:\Users\Fred
for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /ad /b C:\Users\Fred') do Echo Path is %~dpA Name is %~nA
```

See `dir /?` and `for /?`

Comment: Noodles, thank you for responding.  But you misunderstood. This isn't
a directory question. I am using a string and want the last folder
of the string given.