# Windows batch file to list the file from one folder into csv / txt file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

I need a .bat and .sh script to list the all the *.xml files from source folder into one csv/txt file and copy csv/txt file into destination folder.

```
@ECHO OFF
NET USE X: /DELETE
NET USE X: \\SERVER\TEST
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo. > X:\XML_Response\xml_file_list.csv
set searchid="%<OrderNumber>"
for /f %%a in ('findstr /i /m %searchid% X:\XML_Response\*.xml') do (
  echo %%a >> X:\XML_Response\xml_file_list.csv
)
NET USE X: /DELETE
```

Above code give me list of files with path. I just want to have filenames.

```
X:\XML_Response\SO2001.xml 
X:\XML_Response\SO2002.xml
```

I need only

```
SO2001.xml
SO2002.xml
```

Can anyone help

Comment: You need to add code of what you have done so far?

Comment: @Sunil, updated message. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split the filename from a full path in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252980/how-to-split-the-filename-from-a-full-path-in-batch)

Comment: @Sunil, Thanks for the link. I use %%nxa for eco and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shorten your script and still output what you asked for.

```bat
@PushD \\SERVER\TEST\XML_Response
@FindStr/MILC:"<OrderNumber>" *.xml>xml_file_list.csv
```

Comment: thanks. Could you please suggest what should be the script if we don't need to search for string <OrderNumber>, just find and list all the xml files from the folder.

Comment: After almost three weeks, the least you could have done was to mark the answer as accepted, not to ask a completely different question. Change line `2` to `@Dir /B/A-D-L *.xml>"xml_file_list.csv"`.