# How do I get a relative path out of a windows batch file using echo?

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo, text-formatting

How do I get relative directories / partial paths to display as echo output from a windows .bat file?

[How to split the filename from a full path in batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252980/how-to-split-the-filename-from-a-full-path-in-batch)

Talks about everything but.

I've found drive letters, filenames, extensions, shortened (8.3) names, and full paths - but no relative paths.

I'm running a recursive `FOR /R` loop; which traverses sub-directories.  I would like something - that doesn't have twenty characters of useless path info - that tells me which directory each duplicate file lives in... without hardcoding the .bat file to live in a certain directory/path?

Maybe a solution would be to measure the length of the script's path and cut that off of the front of the full path?  But I don't know how to manipulate that.

Script could be in many locations:

```
F:\a.bat<BR>
F:\Dir1\fileA.txt<BR>
F:\Dir20\fileA.txt

C:\Users\Longusername\Desktop\Container\a.bat<BR>
C:\Users\Longusername\Desktop\Container\Dir1\fileA<BR>
C:\Users\Longusername\Desktop\Container\Dir20\fileA
```

And right now the only options I have for output are (`%%~nxG`):

```
fileA.txt
fileA.txt
```

Which doesn't tell me which directory each file is in...or (`%%~pnxG`)

```
\Users\Longusername\Desktop\Container\Dir1\fileA.txt
\Users\Longusername\Desktop\Container\Dir20\fileA.txt
```

What I'd like, from any location:

```
\Dir1\fileA.txt
\Dir20\fileA.txt
```

Could be missing the leading `\`, but that's negligible.  Other options than echo are permissible if they'll work on most window machines.  They may lead to more questions, though - as I've figured out my other pieces with echo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

quite easy, if you think about it: just remove the current directory path (`%cd%`):

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%a in (*.txt) do (
  set "x=%%a"
  echo with \:    !x:%cd%\=\!
  echo without \: !x:%cd%\=!
)
```

By the way: `\folder\file` always refers to the root of the drive (`x:\folder\file`), so it's not exactly a relative path.

Comment: Perfect.  I hadn't found current-directory.  Shoulda looked harder.

Comment: It's always the obvious, that's hard to see... `;)`

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the already accepted answer, but with delayed expansion enabled only where needed. This should correctly output filenames containing **`!`** characters.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "TopLevel=C:\Users\LongUserName"

For /R "%TopLevel%" %%A In ("*.txt") Do (
    Set "_=%%A"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo=!_:*%TopLevel%=!
    EndLocal
)

Pause
```

You could also use `Set "TopLevel=%~dp0"`, *(the running script's directory)* or `Set "TopLevel=%~dp0.."`, *(the running script's parent directory)*

---

One potential benefit of the above method is that you can also use a location relative to the current directory for the value of `%TopLevel%` too, (in this case, *based upon the initial example*, the current directory would be `C:\Users`):

```bat
Set "TopLevel=LongUserName"
```

*Although this would only work correctly if `LongUserName` didn't already exist as content of the path earlier in the tree.*

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`xcopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) together with its `/S` (include sub-directories) and `/L` (list but do not copy) options since it returns relative paths then, so you do not have to do any string manipulation, which might sometimes be a bit dangerous, particularly when the current directory is the root of a drive:

```cmd
xcopy /L /S /I /Y /R ".\*.txt" "\" | find ".\"
```

The appended [`find` command](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) constitutes a filter that removes the summary line `# File(s)` from the output.

---

To capture the output of the aforementioned command line just use a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html):

```cmd
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
    xcopy /L /S /I /Y /R ".\*.txt" "\" ^| find ".\"
') do (
    rem // Do something with each item:
    echo/%%I
)
```